# По каким причинам в Swift 3 будут удалены инкремент и декремент (++ и --)?

Tags: ios, swift

Потихоньку начинаю изучать Swift и программирование вообще. В одном из уроков рассказывается про инкремент, декремент, постфиксную, префиксную формы записи и прочее. Но попробовав получаю такое предупреждение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. с английским туго как и с программированием (близко к нулю) с Гугл переводчиком стало понятно, что это все будет удалено в третьей версии. Но почему? По описанию очень удобные вещи.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

О-о, на эту тему опубликован **[целый документ](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md#disadvantages-of-these-operators)**, предлагающий удаление. По всей видимости, предложение было **принято**. Из значимых аргументов **против**:

- **Не экономят место.**
  По сравнению с `x += 1` выражение `x++` не особо-то короче.
- **Конфликтуют с семантикой остального языка.**
  В Swift присваиания и схожие изменяющие действия возвращают `Void`. Эти — нет.
- **Запутывают разработчиков.**
  Код, использующий возвращаемые значения этих операторов, очень тяжело воспринимается.

  - Swift определяет порядок вычисления своих конструкций, поэтому `foo(++a, a++)`... хотя бы ведёт себя **известным образом** (в С++, скажем, такой роскоши нет), но для понимания нужно знать *дебри* языка.
    А можно, где это важно, произвести изменения заранее в нужном порядке. Полученный код будет даже лучше отражать алгоритм.
- **Редко применимы.**
  Они применимы к довольно небольшому числу типов: целым и вещественным числам, чему-нибудь итератороподобному... но для комплексных чисел, матриц и т. п. они просто не имеют смысла.
- **Редко нужны.**
  Где использовать их? В циклах? В Swift уже достаточно синтаксических удобств для них (`for-in`, диапазоны, `enumerate`, `map` и другие), поэтому подобные конструкции в идиоматичном Swift-коде не должны возникать вообще.

---

Считаю нужным предупредить, что *сам я не знаю Swift*, но со стороны Ruby, где этого семейства операторов [нет и не было](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/2710), это выглядит очень осмысленным изменением.

Когда можно безопасно инкапсулировать сложные способы итерации внутрь классов-генераторов (или других аналогичных механизмов: в Ruby это методы с блоками), частое использование сокращений вроде `++` и `--` перестаёт иметь смысл.

А когда конструкция используется редко, мало смысла иметь в языке её сокращённый синоним: это лишнее усложнение синтаксиса*, что плохо действует на понимание кода программистами и как следствие на стабильность итогового продукта.

Напоминаю также, что ["ошибка на единицу" очень часто встречающаяся штука](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83).

---

* `--x` можно распознать и как `-(-x)`, два применения унарного минуса, что несколько отличается от того, что делает предекремент — подобные синтаксические неоднозначности делают язык более сложным в использовании, поэтому от них есть смысл избавляться

Comment: Спасибо за подробные разъяснения. Надо учить английский чтоб легче с программированием было, но совсем не идёт (